# Labview: error in accessing server addres space

Tags: labview, opc-ua

I am trying to access the server address space and I am getting this Error.

---

LabVIEW:  (Hex 0xFFFA8EBB) The node path refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space

---

The server is on a Plc and I am connected via Lan. the information i have is

Server-URL:                 opc.tcp://192.168.1.135:4840

[image]

Namespace-URI:          urn:B&R/pv/

I have tried different things but i am not sure how to access the variables in address space. any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: I know nothing about OPC, but are you sure you're allowed to have the `&` character in those addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B&R Publishes the Endpoints of your data in a fairly consistent manner. If you use a OPC UA browsing tool, you will find that the address space visible to Labview should start with

```
PLC.Modules.<Default>
```

B&R Automation Studio requires that you complete the default OPC UA configuration. Within that configuration you would need to enable the nodes/endpoints in question. You can then access these nodes in Labview.

You should check the following:

- Under your controller, confirm that you have enabled OPC UA in the
  configuration view.
- Next, check that you have added a OPC UA Default View File to your
  configuration for the hardware you are running.
- Finally, in that file, ensure that you have enabled the   endpoint/variable and that
  it has at least the read permission. The quickest and most expedient
  way is to ensure that you have gone to the top level of the OPC UA
  Default View File and added the *Everyone* role and that *Read* is
  enabled. This will cascade down to all enabled endpoints.

Save this and make sure it has been built and added to your controller. You should be able to access endpoints then.

For example, if I have a program called "LampController" running in B&R with a variable called switchState it would be addressed by:

```
PLC.Modules.<Default>.LampController.switchState
```

Comment: spot on. I mange to find it myself somehow. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %26; in place of an ampersand. The ampersand is used to delimit the URI from the query segment. It's pretty unusual to even have an ampersand in a URI. Are you sure you typed it right?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I dont know about the ampersand. mittop gave the correct answer.